# Input placeholders not showing up

Tags: html

I'm not sure why my placeholders are not showing. Here is the code.

```
<label>Input here:</label><span><input placeholder="Enter Epoch Time" type="number" id='my-id-is-here'></span>

<label>Input2 here:</label><span><input placeholder="10" type="number" id='my-id2-is-here'></span>
```

When I load the page I don't get any placeholders just blank inputs.

Thanks.

Comment: Seems [to work](http://jsfiddle.net/kY8dG/).On which browser are you testing? IE8 ?

Comment: your input tag is written as self-closing without the front slash at the end. May not fix problem, but that part is wrong. <input type="text" placeholder="My Placeholder" />

Comment: Thanks I will correct the input tag.

Comment: A `/` is **NOT** necessary. It's probably your browser or a dumb typo elsewhere. Also, why are you mixing `'` and `"`?

Comment: the html is being rendered by rhino and being displayed on an android device.

Comment: What browser: Come in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/G5VgY/

Comment: I don't see any problem in your code. Make sure you have declared html5 DOCTYPE and using an updated browser.

Comment: I'm leaning towards some is messing up with rhino because it does seem to work with other browsers. Maybe the version of rhino im using doesn't support html5?

Comment: "*displayed on an android device*" Helps if you said that up front in your question.

Comment: According to http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-placeholder ... IE8 and below doesn't support Placeholder, just for reference :)

Answer (score 1):

try this solution:

```
jQuery(function() {
   jQuery.support.placeholder = false;
   p = document.createElement('form');
   if('placeholder' in p) jQuery.support.placeholder = true;
});

$(function() {
   if(!$.support.placeholder) { 
      var active = document.activeElement;
      $('input[type="text"], textarea').focus(function () {
         if ($(this).attr('placeholder') != '' && $(this).val() == $(this).attr('placeholder')) {
            $(this).val('').removeClass('hasPlaceholder');
         }
      }).blur(function () {
         if ($(this).attr('placeholder') != '' && ($(this).val() == '' || $(this).val() == $(this).attr('placeholder'))) {
            $(this).val($(this).attr('placeholder')).addClass('hasPlaceholder');
         }
      });
      $('input[type="text"], textarea').blur();
      $(active).focus();
      $('form:eq(0)').submit(function () {
         $('input[type="text"].hasPlaceholder, textarea.hasPlaceholder').val('');
      });
   }
});
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this script uses jQuery to override all browsers, not just those that don't implement their own default handling of this (Placeholder) HTML5 attribute (e.g., less than Internet Explorer 10).

Answer (score 1):

This jQuery plugin should do the trick...

https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder

Supports down to IE6

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solid fix using [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/), I've tested this back to IE5:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Placeholder Fix</title>
</head>
<body>
    <label>Input here:</label><span><input placeholder="Enter Epoch Time" type="number" id='my-id-is-here'></span>
    <label>Input2 here:</label><span><input placeholder="10" type="number" id='my-id2-is-here'></span>
    <style type="text/css">
        .placeholder {
            color: red;
            font-weight: normal;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/modernizr/modernizr-2.7.1.js"></script>
    <script>
        if (!Modernizr.input.placeholder) {
            alert('in')
            $('[placeholder]').focus(function () {
                var input = $(this);
                if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
                    input.val('');
                    input.removeClass('placeholder');
                }
            }).blur(function () {
                var input = $(this);
                if (input.val() == '' || input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
                    input.addClass('placeholder');
                    input.val(input.attr('placeholder'));
                }
            }).blur();
            $('[placeholder]').parents('form').submit(function () {
                $(this).find('[placeholder]').each(function () {
                    var input = $(this);
                    if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
                        input.val('');
                    }
                })
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The placeholder text will turn Red whenever the page loads in a browser that doesn't handle HTML5 attributes like `placeholder` just to prove that Modernizr is only going to add/handle the HTML5 `placeholder` attribute if the browser doesn't, you can obviously change the text from Red to the standard `#999` or any color you'd like.

Enjoy!